# The delta parameter of Assert.AreEqual thinks I'm passing a string instead of a double

Tags: c#, string, double, assert

This is the function I'm trying to use:
[image]

I threw in some double just for an example, and this is my error:
[image]

Likewise, I've tried ints and floats instead, but it always thinks I'm trying to give it a string. What did I do wrong?

I'm using Visual Studio on a Windows 10 64bit, though I don't think that'll help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In reality, the function you see there called f5.Evaluate(VarLookup) was to blame. It was actually returning an object instead of a double as I had supposed, so the method was expecting a string instead of a double. In short, it wasn't so much the program expecting a string where there was a double, it was the actual value that was incorrect.